# r error in str_replace_all function

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with a column having rows like this;

1. "emergency room" OR "emergency medicine" OR "emergency department"
2. "Allergy" OR "rhinitis" OR "asthma" OR "atopic eczema"

I want to replace all closing quotes ' " ' at the end of each keyword with ' "[Title/Abstract] ' in all rows. The final result should be like below;

1. "emergency room"[Title/Abstract] OR "emergency medicine"[Title/Abstract] OR "emergency department"[Title/Abstract]
2. "Allergy"[Title/Abstract] OR "rhinitis"[Title/Abstract] OR "asthma"[Title/Abstract] OR "atopic eczema"[Title/Abstract]

I am using the following code;

```
newdf <- df %>% mutate_all(funs(str_replace_all(., """, ""[Title/Abstract]")))
```

But getting the error;

> Error: unexpected string constant in "subsetdf_new <- subsetdf %>%
>   mutate_all(funs(str_replace_all(., """, ""[Title/Abstract]")))

Comment: You'll have to properly quote the quotation marks. You can't have `"""`, for example. You could try with `"\""`.

Comment: When you are using a special character like `"` you need to specifially tell `R` you mean that character itself. This is done by *escaping* the character using the `\` symbol. So when you put `"""` you need to put `"\""`. But that is only one problem you are having. Even if you fix this, your code still won't do what you want. If you want more detailed help **you will need to post a snippet of your data the way it actually is**, and very carefully. The quotation marks in your examples contain non-ASCII characters. This will complicate matters.

Comment: I tried escaping the quotes but that isn't working as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand exactly what your strings look like and what you're trying to change, but if the bit you're trying to replace is always the last character, you can operate on that using regex. You're looking for a non-word character (regex: `\\W`) at the end of your string (regex: `$`), so you should be good with using `\\W$` as the search term in your call to `str_replace_all`.

But as is mentioned in one of the comments, you also need to escape the quotation mark in your replacement, using a backslash.